# Alert when data changes - JSON and AJAX and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I wrote the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>JSON On-change Sample</title>
</head>
<body>
    <style>
      span {
        font-weight: bold;
      }
    </style>

    <div id="placeholder"></div>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
$(document).ready(function(){ 
//DOCUMENT READY FUNCTION
    loadData();
}); 

    function loadData() {
  $.getJSON('data.json', function(data) {
        var output="<span>";

            output+= data.response.items[0].state;
            output+= data.response.items[1].state;

        output+="</span>";
        document.getElementById("placeholder").innerHTML=output;

                var initial = (data.response.items[0].state);
                var initialSecond = (data.response.items[1].state);

        if (initial>0 || initialSecond>0) {
        document.title= 'State 1:' + " " + initial + " " + "and" + " " + "State 2:" + " " + initialSecond;
}
               $('#placeholder').change(function() {
                alert("Changed!");
                });

  });
  setTimeout("loadData()",800);
}
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

It's purpose is to simply update every 800 milliseconds and update the results on the page. It works.

The problem is that I want a simple alert whenever either of the state of the two items changes, saying which product ID change from which state to which state.

I can't even seem to be able to get the alert first, not even mentioning telling it which product changed and from what state to what state.

Why isn't my alert working? The jQuery documentation state that this... this should be functional.

EDIT:

Solved with the help of blunderboy's solution below.

Here's how it ended-up looking:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>JSON On-change Sample</title>
</head>
<body>
    <style>
      span {
        font-weight: bold;
      }
      #placeholderOne, #placeholderTwo {
        font-weight: bold; 
        margin-bottom: 15px; 
        text-align: center; 
        color: #b20000;
      }
      h3, h4 { 
        margin-bottom: 15px; 
        text-align: center;
      }
    </style>
    <h3>The numbers represent the state of the two products. Get the alert and the update via AJAX by changing the state data in the data.json file and saving it.</h3>
    <h4> Product 1: </h4>
    <div id="placeholderOne"></div>
    <h4> Product 2: </h4>
    <div id="placeholderTwo"></div>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
$(document).ready(function(){ 
//DOCUMENT READY FUNCTION
    loadData();
}); 

function loadData() {
  $.getJSON('data.json', function(data) {
    var output = data.response.items[0].state;
    var outputTwo = data.response.items[1].state;

    // Cache the initialState before putting updated value in it
    var initialStateOne = document.getElementById("placeholderOne").innerHTML;
    var initialStateTwo = document.getElementById("placeholderTwo").innerHTML;

    document.getElementById("placeholderOne").innerHTML=output;
    document.getElementById("placeholderTwo").innerHTML=outputTwo;
    var initial = (data.response.items[0].state);
    var initialSecond = (data.response.items[1].state);

    if (initial > 0 || initialSecond > 0) {
      document.title= 'State 1:' + " " + initial + " " + "and" + " " + "State 2:" + " " + initialSecond;
    }

    if (initialStateOne != output && initialStateOne > 0) {
      alert("Product ID " + data.response.items[0].product_id + " state changed from " + initialStateOne + " to " + data.response.items[0].state);
          if (initialStateTwo != outputTwo && initialStateTwo > 0) {
      alert("Product ID " + data.response.items[1].product_id + " state changed from " + initialStateTwo + " to " + data.response.items[1].state);
    }
    };


});
  setTimeout("loadData()",800);
}
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Change event does not work on DIVs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [jQuery Change Event API](http://api.jquery.com/change/). It clearly says change event is limited to textarea, select and input. That's why you can not get this working.

Instead you could compare previous and the latest values manually and alert your change event.

Your code will look like this:

```
function loadData() {
  $.getJSON('data.json', function(data) {
    var output="<span>";
        output+= data.response.items[0].state;
        output+= data.response.items[1].state;
        output+="</span>";

    // Cache the initialState before putting updated value in it
    var initialState = document.getElementById("placeholder").innerHTML;

    document.getElementById("placeholder").innerHTML=output;
    var initial = (data.response.items[0].state);
    var initialSecond = (data.response.items[1].state);

    if (initial > 0 || initialSecond > 0) {
      document.title= 'State 1:' + " " + initial + " " + "and" + " " + "State 2:" + " " + initialSecond;
    }

    if (initialState != output) { //See this is the only change
      alert("Changed!");
    };
});
setTimeout("loadData()",800);
```

Comment: This seems to work... to an extent. Here's the updated code: http://jsfiddle.net/D2zH4/. I got it to work and recognize the Product ID from the JSON file. The only problems now are: 1) The 2nd alert won't stop looping and 2) How do I get it to have no initial alert when first loading the page, only on additional changes?

Answer (score 0):

Here is another answer to your problem. You can use [DOM Mutation Event: DOMSubtreeModified](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Mutation_events?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Web/Guide/API/DOM/Events/Mutation_events) to figure out the changes in the subtree of an element. Here is [JSbin Demo](http://jsbin.com/ohEjAje/2/edit?html,js,output)

## HTML

```
<div id='a'></div>
```

## JS

```
var $a = $('#a');
$a.on('DOMSubtreeModified', function() {
  alert('Changed');
});

$a.html('This is test1');
$a.html('This is test2');
```

PS: Please note that this method will also call the event handler when you change any element inside this div. So you better remove this event handler when no longer required or handle such cases gracefully.